# How can I control an app on my iOS device from Mac or PC

Tags: ios, development, remote-control

I would like to take control of my app on an iOS device (mostly an iPhone) from my MacBook Pro or Windows, doesn't matter which one.

I know that it can be accomplished via Veency, and that's exactly what I need - but I do NOT want to jailbreak my iPhone.

Is there a similar legal alternative?

If not - is it something I could develop perhaps, or will I run into some SDK limitations for such a thing?

Comment: Generally, if the only solution you can find is a jailbreak solution, it's the only solution. As hotpaw2 said (accept that answer), the sandbox nature of stock iOS disallows anything like this. You can control a Mac or PC from an iOS device, but not the other way around.

Comment: Plus the motto of jailbreaking is exactly what you requested: "take control of your iOS". And [it's not illegal](http://www.cnet.com/8301-17918_1-20011824-85.html) for quite some time now.

Comment: Actually, I really just need to control my own App, for testing purposes. I'll comment below.

Answer (score 7):

All iOS SDK apps work within a security sandbox, and thus have no access or control over any other apps (with a few tiny exceptions for registered URLs). You could take control of you own app, but no others, including Apple's, on a stock OS device.

Comment: Thanks! I should clarify - I do want to control my Own App mostly, for automatic testing purposes. 
So how do I do that? What is needed on iOS and on PC/Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution using TeamViewer QuickSupport. Install quicksupport for ios on iphone and connect using teamviewer.

I can't test, it requires ios11.

Answer (score -1):

Turn on Home Sharing using Remote

1.Connect iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch to a Wi-Fi network on the same local network as your Mac, PC, or Apple TV.

2. Open the Remote app on your iOS device.
3. Turn on Home Sharing from the Remote Settings screen.
4. Sign in to the same Apple ID you used on your other devices.

Comment: He wants to control his iOS device from a desktop PC, Remote works the opposite way