# How can I control my iPhone from my Mac?

Tags: macos, ios, remote-control

Yes, there are a million ways to control your Mac from your iOS device, but I want to do the opposite.

The scenario is that I'm sitting at my computer, with my iPhone charging in a stand in front of me, and something on the device interrupts me.  I want to respond in a second or two, without having to remove the device from the stand, or take my hands away from my keyboard and trackpad.

I do *not* need to see the iPhone's screen on my computer's monitor.

Is this possible?  If so, how can I do it?

## UPDATE

I am not asking [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9383/how-can-i-control-ios-device-from-mac-or-pc), which is only concerned with controlling one single app, an entirely different situation.  To quote that question:

> Actually, I really just need to control my own App, for testing purposes.

Nor am I asking [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128547/control-and-see-iphone-from-mac-with-broken-iphone-screen) which is specifically about *seeing the screen* of a broken iPhone, which I explicitly stated I don't care about.

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128547/control-and-see-iphone-from-mac-with-broken-iphone-screen

Comment: To help clarify this further, when you say *...something on the device interrupts me* can you be more specific on what you mean by 'something'? Are you wanting to cover just Apple's default iOS notifications relating to messages, email, FaceTime, etc? Or do you want to be able to do this regardless of what the notification is about (i.e. it could be about an iMessage, or it could be about a 3rd party game too, etc)? Also, can you give an example of how you'd want to be able to *respond in a second or two, without having to...take my hands away from my keyboard and trackpad*?

Comment: An interruption is normally a notification from some app, that I need or want to take care of. I want to be able to not only type into apps (I can already do this through blue tooth) but I want to be able to send any gestures to the iOS device.  Ideally there would be keyboard short cuts for things like switching between apps, going to the home screen, etc. If I can do everything I need to through my computer, I save lots of time.  I can use my keyboard and trackpad in seconds, without having to remove the device from its dock, etc.